# ProgressBar while loading ListView (using AsyncTask)

Tags: android-layout, android

I'm trying to show a progress bar when loading a custom ListView and afterwards - hide it.
I'm using ASync task, but for some reason - The content view is not set and the previous layout view is stuck until all the list view is loaded.

Here is my code:

```
private ListView listViewGameResults;   
    protected View dialogLayout;
    protected ArrayList<Game> listGames;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.adresults);
        GameResultsLoader gameResultsLoader = new GameResultsLoader();              
        gameResultsLoader.execute();        
    }

    private class GameResultsLoader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {       
        private GameResultsAdapter adapter;

        public GameResultsLoader() {            
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() { 
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) { 
            try {
            listGames = GameResultsCache.getInstance().getGameResults();
            adapter = new GameResultsAdapter(getBaseContext(), listGames);
            listViewGameResults = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewGameResults);
            } 
            catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                finish();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void res) {
            listViewGameResults.setAdapter(adapter);
            listViewGameResults.setDivider(null);
            listViewGameResults.setDividerHeight(0);
            ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressbar_loading);
            pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);            
        }
    }
```

ProgressBar and ListView in my layout:

```
<ProgressBar
       style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"
       android:id="@+id/progressbar_loading"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <ListView
         android:id="@+id/listViewGameResults"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
         android:layout_below="@+id/upperstrip"
         android:layout_above="@+id/ivDownStrip" />
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to set default visibility of `progressBar` gone.and `onPreExecute()`set Visible and `onPostExecute()`set gone.

```
<ProgressBar
       style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"
       android:id="@+id/progressbar_loading"
       android:visibility="gone"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <ListView
         android:id="@+id/listViewGameResults"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
         android:layout_below="@+id/upperstrip"
         android:layout_above="@+id/ivDownStrip" />
```

your Activity should look like this

```
public class demo extends Activity{
    private ListView listViewGameResults;   
        protected View dialogLayout;
        protected ArrayList<Game> listGames;
    progressBar progress;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
            setContentView(R.layout.adresults);
            progress=(ProgressBar)findViewByid(R.id.progressbar_loading);
            GameResultsLoader gameResultsLoader = new GameResultsLoader(this);              
            gameResultsLoader.execute();        
        }
    }
```

Use one separate class for `AsyncTask`

```
public class GameResultsLoader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {       
        private GameResultsAdapter adapter;
        Demo demo;
        public GameResultsLoader(Demo demo) {   
        this.demo=demo;         
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() { 
        demo.progress.setvisibility(View.Visible);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) { 
            try {
            listGames = GameResultsCache.getInstance().getGameResults();
            adapter = new GameResultsAdapter(getBaseContext(), listGames);
            listViewGameResults = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewGameResults);
            } 
            catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                finish();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void res) {
            listViewGameResults.setAdapter(adapter);
            listViewGameResults.setDivider(null);
            listViewGameResults.setDividerHeight(0);
            ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressbar_loading);
            demo.progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);            
        }
    }
```

Comment: but the progress bar is running already when doing setContentView.
Look at my xml.
I just need to hide it. It's not a progress dialog.
My problem is that the content view isn't show.

Comment: The issue is not regarding the ProgressBar. The issue is when setting content view it doesn't set and it waits for the whole listview to load.

Comment: That's why i'm saying,You need to use AsyncTask for load whole listview in the background of the AsyncTask.Use setContextView on Oncreate().

Comment: That is what i'm doing. I'm setting the content view in the "OnCreate" method and then loading the listview in "doInBackground" in AsyncTask

Answer (score 2):

if your using asnkTask that is work on main Thread so application is much more load.so better solution is using Service.class.
**downlaod this example** Check this link all are solution are there and download it:
you have to also get list from relaunch this application.
https://github.com/PankajSavaliyaGit/Upload-List

Comment: Don't add links as answer, provide some code example on the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

you have to write code to start progressDialog in preExecute method and at the postExecute dismiss it.

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
     proDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
     proDialog.setTitle("App name");
     proDialog.setMessage("Loding...");
     proDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
     //proDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.)
     proDialog.setCancelable(true);
     proDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void res) {
     proDialog.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: I don't want a progress dialog. I want a progress bar without a message.

Comment: change following code:  mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL); and in the progressUpdate set value for your progress bar .

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you can do is put Progress bar code after `OnCreate` method. But the best thing is to create a simple method for Progress bar and only call it in `OnCreate` method.

The following code worked fine for me:

```
private void showDialog() {
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Have a nice time");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait while showing Titles :) ");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progressDialog.show();
}
```

And then call this method in `OnCreate`

```
showDialog();
```

You can stop Progress when the data is ready to view using:

```
progressDialog.dismiss();
```

I hope this is helpful.