# Unable to dismiss progress bar in AsyncTask

Tags: android

I want to load datas from a list to gridview with a loading effect using progressbar.Im getting items from a webservice.The problem i face is im unable to dismiss the progress bar even after showing the gridview.I can see the gridview with items but progress bar is still running .What am i doing wrong here.

```
private void testAsyncTask() {
        Log.e("Im in testAsyncTask()", "");
        new AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>() {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {

                progress_Dialog = ProgressDialog.show(a, "", "Loading");


                Log.e("Im in onPreExecute", "");
                // super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected Integer doInBackground(Object... params) {
                MenuService menuService = new MenuServiceImpl();
                PartnerMenuServiceResponse partnerMenu = menuService
                        .getPartnerMenu();
                jewellist = partnerMenu.getMenu().getMenuEntries();
                Log.e("Im in doInBackground", "");
                System.gc();

                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // super.onPostExecute(result);asd
                Log.e("Im in onPostExecute", "");
                 if (progress_Dialog.isShowing()) {
                     progress_Dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                 ShopGridAdapter adapter = new ShopGridAdapter(ShopGridActivity.this, jewellist);
                 AllJewelgridView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                //AllJewelgridView.setAdapter(new ShopGridAdapter(
                    //  ShopGridActivity.this, jewellist));

                if (AllJewelgridView.getCount() <= 0) {
                    MyAlertDialog.ShowAlertDialog(ShopGridActivity.this, "",
                            "No data found.", "OK");
                }
                progress_Dialog.dismiss();
            }

        }.execute();

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    progress_Dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progress_Dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    progress_Dialog.show();
}
```

**EDIT :**

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
    Log.e("Im in onPostExecute", "");     <------ ARE YOU ABLE SEE THIS IN logcat ?
    progress_Dialog();
}
```

It may possible onPostExecute() not called. So to confirm check logcat

Comment: He can able to see progress Dialog but not dismiss it .

Comment: @playmaker420: your progress is not finished yet

Comment: Guys i found the problem. I called the  testAsyncTask() function twice in onCreate().Now it seems everything is ok.Thanks for the replies

Comment: @playmaker420 so what happen if testAsynchTask() called twice??in that case onPost will also be called twice

Answer (score 1):

You need to put some code in your `AsyncTask`

```
 ProgressDialog progress=null;
progress=ProgressDialog.show(this,"title","loading..").show();//put this code in onPreExecute()
progress.dismiss();//put this code in onPostExecute()
```

for more [ProgressBar while loading ListView (using AsyncTask)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12280336/progressbar-while-loading-listview-using-asynctask/12280526#12280526)

Comment: yea.Im using this already.I solved the problem it was in the onCreate()

Answer (score 0):

You can write in onPostExecute method may help you.

```
 if ( progress_Dialog != null) {
             progress_Dialog.cancel();
        }
```

Comment: Problem was in onCreate().Thanks for replying

Comment: your problem still remaining ?