# Progress Dialog does not display due to use of thread.get() method

Tags: android, multithreading, web-services, thread-safety

I want to display a Progress Dialog while I have two threads running one after the other, but my data structure that I use gets populated via the threads, becomes null. Thus I used thread.get() method to wait for the thread to be finished....not sure how I can get around this here is an example of one of my Async Threads:

```
private void performDetailSearch(String reference) {

    String addplus = searchterm.replace(" ", "+");  
    RestClientDS restpSd = new RestClientDS();
    String url = PLACES_DETAILS_URL +"reference="+ reference + "&sensor=false&key=" + API_KEY;
    Log.d("url",url);
    String[] URL = {url};
    restpSd.execute(URL);

    try {
        restpSd.get();
    } 
    catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (ExecutionException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use AsyncTask for this taskl,for more details see my [answer][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12280336/progressbar-while-loading-listview-using-asynctask/12280526#12280526

Answer (score 0):

Use **[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)** instead of Thread and call another task after one gets completed.

AsyncTask can be called this way `new FetchData().execute();`

```
private class FetchData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(HomeActivity.this);

    /** progress dialog to show user that the backup is processing. */
    /** application context. */

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(
                R.string.Loading_String));
        this.dialog.show();
    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {
        try {

            //do your background work

            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("tag", "error", e);
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {

        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

        if (success) {
            //call the another asynctask from here.
           // new FetchData2().execute();
        }
    }
}
```