# How to pass values to AsyncTask Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

This is the first time i am using AsyncTask and probably a little confused as well, about passing the values.

I have 4 `ArrayList<String>` s, which contain data that should be inserted into the database. I want this insertion to be done in background. There will be a minimum of 50 rows to be inserted into the database and 1 row is inserted at a time, by taking passing values from 4 arraylists that i have.

Can someone guide me on how to do this?

Now i create a subclass InsertData that extends AsyncTask :::

```
private class InsertData extends AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>{

        @Override
        protected Result doInBackground(Params... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }   
}
```

I have values in 4 arraylists, in which i need to retrieve 1 entry from each arraylist and pass the 4 values to the database. How do i pass these 4 values to the AsyncTask and also, how do i repeat this till there are entries in the arraylists.

Here is the database method that inserts 1 row into the database :::

```
public void insert_row(int count, String image_url, String name, String number) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO contacts VALUES('"+ count +"', '"+ image_url +"', '"+ name +"', '"+ number +"')");
    }
```

If someone can give me a overview on how i can implement this, It would be great.

Comment: you can pass value to the constructor of the asynctask or to doInBackground(). example  @ http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html. doInbackgroudn receiving urls

Comment: You can use constructor fot this fore more have look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12280336/progressbar-while-loading-listview-using-asynctask/12280526#12280526

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the following, and, anyway, you could create constructor for `InsertData` with parameters you need, store them in `InsertData` class fields and use in `doInBackground()`.

```
private class InsertData extends AsyncTask<ArrayList, Progress, Result>{

            @Override
            protected Result doInBackground(ArrayList... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ArrayList list1 = params[0];
                ArrayList list2 = params[1];
                ...
                return null;
            }   
    }
```

Call:

```
InsertData task = new InsertData();
task.execute(yourList1, yourList2, yourList3...);
```

Comment: I will try and get back to you on this.

Comment: Would this answer suffice to solve this problem as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34689357/can-i-pass-a-variable-into-a-private-asyncronous-method

Answer (score 2):

You can directly pass the lists to the `doInBackground()` like this and do all your 50 iterations there.

```
private class InsertData extends AsyncTask<List<String>, Progress, Result>{

    @Override
    protected Result doInBackground(List<String>... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<String> list1 = params[0];
        List<String> list2 = params[1];
        List<String> list3 = params[2];
        List<String> list4 = params[3];

        // Do the 50 iterations here.        

        return null;
    }   
}
```

And you can pass the lists to this `AsyncTask` like this:-

```
new InsertData().execute(list1, list2, list3, list4);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass like this

```
private class InsertData extends AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>{

    public InsertData(String stg1, String stg2, String stg3, String stg4) {

    } 

    @Override
    protected Result doInBackground(Params... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }   
}
```

call asynctask like this

```
InsertData task = new InsertData (stg1, stg2, st3, stg4);    
task.execute();
```

Comment: As i said, I have to repeat the insertion for about 50 times, how do i do that?

Comment: Check how many values are available in arraylist depending on size of that repeat the loop..

Answer (score 0):

Dont Use ArrayList for all the value... Just use One Arraylist. and you can Use bean
e.g

```
ArrayList<ItemBean> aryitem=new ArrayList<ItemBean>();
```

ItemBean is a Bean Class.. so you can set value there.. and retrieve from there.

```
for (int i = 0; i <aryitem; i++)
{
  itemBean= new ItemBean();

  itemBean.set(yourValues);
  itemBean.set(yourValues);

aryItem.add(itemBean);
}
```

Now call your `public void insert_row(int count, String image_url, String name, String number)` in doInBackground and pass aryItem. try this

Comment: if you have to retrieve 50 times then you should use Bean class as I say..It'll be easy for you

Answer (score 0):

i think it might help you.. you can pass value like this..

Calling InsertData (AsynkTask)

```
ArrayList list1,list2,list3,list4;

InsertData insertd = new InsertData(list1,list2,list3,list4)
insertd.execute();
```

in your InsertData.java

```
class InsertData extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>
{
    Context ctx;
    ArrayList li1,li2,li3,li4;
    public InsertData(Context ct,ArrayList l1,ArrayList l2,ArrayList l3,ArrayList l4)
    {
        ctx = ct;

        this.li1 = l1;
        this.li2 = l2;
        this.li3 = l3;
        this.li4 = l4;

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(ct);
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading.. Please Wait..");
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
    }

        @Override
        protected Result doInBackground(Params... params)
        {
            // Do your Work...

            return null;
        }   
}
```