# Can I pass a variable into a private Asyncronous method?

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, parse-platform

Okay so what I'm trying to do is plug in the variable "int putPrice" from this first method (SaveTemplate) into the variable "price" in the second method (SaveTemplateTask).

**First public method:**

```
public boolean SaveTemplate(View view) {

        final EditText txtPrice = new EditText(getContext());
        txtPrice.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(false, false));

        new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
                .setTitle(selectedProduct.getName())
                .setMessage("You will earn every dollar above the base price (" + "USD $" + selectedProduct.getCost() + ") for this item!")
                .setView(txtPrice)
                .setPositiveButton("Sell Product", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                        // putPrice is the variable set by the user. I want to pass this into SaveTemplateTask.
                        int putPrice = Integer.parseInt(txtPrice.getText().toString());
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Saving design", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        new SaveTemplateTask().execute();

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    }
                })
                .show();


        return true;
    }
```

**Second private method:**

```
private class SaveTemplateTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                MainActivity mainActivity = ((MainActivity) getActivity());

                mainActivity.DrawDesignOnResult();

                UUID uuid = mainActivity.SaveResultBitmapToExternalStorage();

                // price is the variable I ultimately want to be determined by putPrice, because this is the variable that is ultimately uploaded to the back-end.
                int price = Integer.parseInt(putPrice);
                String productType = selectedProduct.getSKU();

                mainActivity.UploadExternalFileToServer(uuid.toString());
                ParseHelper.UploadDesignToMarketFeed(GenerateBitmapFromTemplateView(), uuid, price, productType);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
                return false;
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            if(!result) { Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.string.failed_to_save_image, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Design saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

I'm basically just stumped on how to pass the variables between the different classes so that I can ultimately set the price as a function of what the user input originally in the first public class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can pass like a param:

**Second Method:**

```
//First Integer is your param, change in doInBackground too.
private class SaveTemplateTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        Integer paramPutPrice = params[0];
        //.. your logic
    }

}
```

**and in the First Method:**

```
new SaveTemplateTask().execute(putPrice);
```

Comment: Awesome. Worked really well. Still having trouble deciphering how those three parameters works in the AsyncTask. What does the order control?

Comment: <Integer, Integer, Boolean>. Like when the first one was Void, I couldn't use Integar paramPutPrice, but as soon as I changed Void to Integer, it worked. What do the remaining two parameters do, if anything? I've basically learned most of what I know coding just by hacking and slashing at random, so I tend to piece things together backwards.

Comment: @Kris made a good (ok, not too good) picture. Let's explain:

<ParamA, ParamB, ParamC>
**ParamA** - To pass data to asyncTask.
**ParamB** - To count some progress.
**ParamC** - Type of return that the doInBackground have to pass to onPostExecute method.

Answer (score 1):

```
//This is how you should call your 

int parameter=something;//your parameter value
new  MyAsyn().execute(parameter);

//Your AsyncTask class should be 
 class MyAsyn extends AsyncTask<Integer,Integer,Boolean>{
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
```

[image: This is parameter mapping . Will help you understand.]

Image is about parameter mapping with methods.