# NullPointerException when trying to connect android to sql server

Tags: android, sql-server, jdbc

I'm making a log in activity on my android app. I keep getting IOException when trying to connect to the database. I've tried almost everything:
1- I've set the port to 1433
2-I've started the sql browser service
3-I've included the jtds .jar file
4- I've disabled firewall
5- I've enabled TCP/IP service in configuration manager

Here's the query code (it's the function called when button clicked)

```
public void logIn(View view)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),ipValue,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        try {
            DBConnect dbConnect = new DBConnect(getApplicationContext());
            dbConnect.execute();
            LogInStatement="select count(*) from users where username=? AND password=?";
            preparedStatement=dbConnect.conn.prepareStatement(LogInStatement);
            preparedStatement.setString(1,userNameEditText.getText().toString());
            preparedStatement.setString(2,passwordEditText.getText().toString());
            ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                count = rs.getInt(1);
            }
            if (count != 0) {
                Intent userScreenIntent = new Intent(this, UserScreen.class);
                startActivity(userScreenIntent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "بيانات الدخول غير صحيحة", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

And here's the connection code:

```
public class DBConnect extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
    {
        private Context ctx;
        SharedPreferences prefs;
        Connection conn;
        String ipValue;
        public DBConnect(Context ctx)
        {
            this.ctx=ctx;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            //get sharedPreferences here
            prefs = ctx.getSharedPreferences("DoorSystem_SHPREF",
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ipValue=prefs.getString("IP_VALUE",null);
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                    .permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            String ConnURL = null;
            try {

                Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
                ConnURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + ipValue + ":1433;databaseName=doors;user=sam123;password=111;";
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnURL);
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                Log.e("ERRO", se.getMessage());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**Edit:**
The stack trace is now showing me a NullPointerException:

```
07-04 10:17:32.233 20120-20120/port.doorsystem W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-04 10:17:32.243 20120-20120/port.doorsystem W/System.err:     at port.doorsystem.LogIn.logIn(LogIn.java:91)
07-04 10:17:32.243 20120-20120/port.doorsystem W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-04 10:17:32.243 20120-20120/port.doorsystem W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-04 10:17:32.243 20120-20120/port.doorsystem W/System.err:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
07-04 10:17:32.243 20120-20120/port.doorsystem W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4508)
07-04 10:17:32.243 20120-20120/port.doorsystem W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18675)
07-04 10:17:32.243 20120-20120/port.doorsystem W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-04 10:17:32.243 20120-20120/port.doorsystem W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-04 10:17:32.243 20120-20120/port.doorsystem W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-04 10:17:32.243 20120-20120/port.doorsystem W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
07-04 10:17:32.243 20120-20120/port.doorsystem W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-04 10:17:32.243 20120-20120/port.doorsystem W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-04 10:17:32.243 20120-20120/port.doorsystem W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
07-04 10:17:32.243 20120-20120/port.doorsystem W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
07-04 10:17:32.243 20120-20120/port.doorsystem W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you add the stack trace?

Comment: @PiyushShrivastava now it's giving me a NullPointerException

Comment: It is probably due to this line `preparedStatement=dbConnect.conn.prepareStatement(LogInStatement);`. `dbConnect.conn` is initialized in `doInBackground` which is running on a different thread. `prepareStatement` is probably called before `conn` is initialized

Comment: @0xDEADC0DE any modification you'd recommend?

Comment: @SamIbraheem, You can modify the constructor of `DBConnect` to accept a Context and an interface and invoke this interface in onPostExecute of DBConnect. In the implementation of the interface you can put the prepared statement code. That way you are sure that `conn` is initialized and you also don't get a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very sure about this, but I guess you are getting null pointer at `conn`. This might probably be because you are initializing it in an `Async Task` and using it outside it.

In an ideal approach, you should just use the output that an `Async Task` returns. You can return the connection reference (`conn`), or you can prepare your statement in the background by putting your `PreparedStatement` code in the `Async Task` and return the `ResultSet`.

If you can point out the exact line at which you got the exception, I might be able to help you more.

UPDATE: This should work:

Background thread -

```
  protected Connection doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {

            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            ConnURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + ipValue + ":1433;databaseName=doors;user=sam123;password=111;";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnURL);
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            Log.e("ERRO", se.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
        }
        return conn;
    }
```

Login -

```
DBConnect dbConnect = new DBConnect(getApplicationContext());
Connection conn = dbConnect.execute().get();
LogInStatement="select count(*) from users where username=? AND password=?";
preparedStatement=conn.prepareStatement(LogInStatement);
```

Comment: well you are right, its the statement:

preparedStatement=dbConnect.conn.prepareStatement(LogInStatement);

but I can't figure out how to fix it

Comment: @SamIbraheem Just change the return type of `doInBackground()` to `Connection` and catch it in a variable and use it for preparing the statement.

Comment: Thank you for your help but now it's giving me a  android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException 

on the statement  ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

Comment: `NetworkOnMainThreadException` occurs when you do Network tasks on main thread. Do everything in the background thread.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15894418/how-to-pass-values-to-asynctask-android Refer this. :)